# PHP- PDO get metadata from database

Tags: metadata

I want to get the metadata from a database with a table 'friends'

```
id name
1  Herbert
2  LG
3  Levins
```

Here is the code I was trying to get the data.

```
<?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=postgre';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM friends");
$cnt_columns = $stmt->columnCount();
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt_columns; $i++) {
  $metadata = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
  var_dump($metadata);
}

    ?>
```

When I execute the code:, it displays

```
   array
  'native_type' => string 'LONG' (length=4)
  'pdo_type' => int 2
  'flags' => 
    array
      empty
  'table' => string 'friends' (length=7)
  'name' => string 'id' (length=2)
  'len' => int 11
  'precision' => int 0

array
  'native_type' => string 'VAR_STRING' (length=10)
  'pdo_type' => int 2
  'flags' => 
    array
      empty
  'table' => string 'friends' (length=7)
  'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
  'len' => int 60
  'precision' => int 0
```

Till here, it is giving the correct count of rows, but I need the result to display as it looks in the my database like

Output:

```
id name
1  Hebert
2  LG
3  Levins
```

How could I get all my fields as it is like a table in my database using metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Use [columnCount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php).

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM friends");
$cnt_columns = $stmt->columnCount();
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt_columns; $i++) {
  $metadata = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
  var_dump($metadata);
}
```

By the way, [getColumnMeta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) is *experimental*. Not recommended to use. Why do you want to use it?

---

For the desired output, you don't need metadata. Just loop through the results:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// field names
if(count($result) > 0) {
   foreach($result[0] as $k => $v) {
     if(!is_int($k)) {
       echo $k . "\t";
     }
   }
}
echo PHP_EOL;

// data
foreach ($result as $row) {
    foreach($row as $k => $v) {
      if(!is_int($k)) {
        echo $row[$k] . "\t";
      }
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank You..When I take your code, it displays the same array format. I need like the entire table contents as it looks in the database Will it be possible

Comment: You have to work it out by HTML table, or, if in plain text, make it with `\t` , `PHP_EOL`, etc

Comment: Atleast could you give me an idea, its difficult to get the column names:id, name with data

Comment: Sure.. I have edited my code with a required result to be shown

Comment: You do not require "metadata" to get the contents. Wrong direction. See my updated answer.

Comment: The foreach gives only the last row from the updated answer. Let me tell my requirment: I have a PHP form where user can select the database and write a sql query in a textfield, when submitting the form, sql query will execute and display all the table content.

Comment: updated the answer to remove dependency of column names

Comment: Appreciate your help, and now it displays the output :  id name Hartmut. I feel we should use while instead of foreach.

Comment: `while`, `foreach` are looping logic, doesn't affect the output

Comment: Really I don't have any row with name Hartmut

Comment: You should `var_dump($result)` to debug. Post it in question